# OpenGTS platform

Tags: gps, tracker, opengts

I have been currently working with OpenGTS platform, I would like to help me with something.

I want to connect a GPS to the platform is the "GPS TRACKER 103ab" this GPS works under the protocol "TK-103". To see if they could help me connect this device to the platform. I followed the documentation to activate the devic`enter code here`e through SMS to my cell with commands like:

```
Begin123456 = to start the device.
IMEI123456 = so that the device will return the 15 digits.
adminip123456 109.0.0.9 = 8080 to set the ip + port that I am using.
```

The problem is that still can not get connect with the platform, help me.
Facts:

- Opengts
- GPS TRACKER 103ab
- Protocol "TK-103"

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Traccar GPS server](https://www.traccar.org/) to receive data from your device and [integrate it with OpenGTS](https://www.traccar.org/opengts/) if you want to access the data from OpenGTS web interface. Traccar supports more communication protocols than OpenGTS.

Answer (score 0):

The correct command to set ADMINIP is :

```
adminip123456 [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] [xxxx]
```

where the first field is the IP address of your server, must be an address public and accessible from the outside.

and the second field (note that they are only separated by a space) is the port where the server expects the connection , the default is 31272 for tk10x protocol. **NEVER 8080** , this is the port where Tomcat listens.

After setting the ' adminp ' , use the command:

```
fix001m***123456
```

to start position reports every minute.

it is also necessary to set the APN,APNuser,APNpassword from the mobile service provider's of the device.

use the commands:

```
apn123456 datos.personal.com
apnuser123456 gprs
apnpasswd123456 gprs
```

(This is an example using the appropriate data to the service provider's Personal.ar)